# Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm working on a springboot application with keyclock using docker
in application yml file I specified both the issuer and the jwk

```
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://localhost:8080/realms/backend
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:8080/realms/backend/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

this is my security filter chain :

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(ar->ar.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    }
```

However when I try to fetch an api using the token from

I always get
An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set

the jswk-set-uri mentioneed in application.yml is read this way

> "404 Not found
>
> ## Not found
>
> The requested URL /realms/backend/protocol/openid-connect/certs was not found on this server"

My project info:

-Springboot:3.2.3
-Jdk 17

Docker compose yml :

```
  keycloak:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/keycloak:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_CREATE_ADMIN_USER=true
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    volumes:
      - ./mynewtheme:/opt/bitnami/keycloak/themes/mynewtheme
      - /path/to/init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Comment: what version of keycloak are you running ?

Comment: I'm pulling the latest image from docker